# Class cast exception on spinner item selection

Tags: android, spinner, adapter, classcastexception

I have a spinner populated with custom adapter.

My code used to bind data to spinner is

```
private void setOperatorSpinnerAdapter(Spinner spinner, String data) {

    listOperator = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            model2 = new LiabModel();
            model2.setName(jsonObject.optString("name"));
            listOperator.add(model2);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    adapter_liab = new CustomListAdapter_liab(LiabilitiesActivity.this, listOperator);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter_liab);
}
```

My issue is with item selection. I am getting error as

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to Model.LiabModel

My spinner item click code is

```
spnr.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            try {
                LiabModel model2 = (LiabModel) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                liab_type = model2.getName();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("exc",""+e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Im getting Class Cast exception in
"LiabModel model2 = (LiabModel) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);" this line. Why is that happening?

Comment: is it same.. `spinner` and `spnr` ?

Comment: yes, I'm passing spnr to setOperatorSpinnerAdapter() method.

Comment: then bro,, set the listener inside the method..

Comment: That too not working, same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get selected value either by this

```
 LiabModel model2 = (LiabModel) spnr.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

or by if listOperator is accessable

LiabModel model2 = listOperator.get(position);

Comment: i dint found any error in your code , so i gave you 2 more alternative